# Avoid "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" in ios deep linking

Tags: ios

We are getting a "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" popup in safari browser with ios deep linking implementation.

We are using iframe technique for deep linking implementation.

Before opening an App store page, we are getting this popup. After clicking OK, we are able to open the App store page.

How to avoid this

> Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

popup before launching the App store page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)